# Given $N(4,9)$ determine $P(1 \leq X < 10)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Given $X$ ~ $N(4,9)$ determine $P(1 \leq X < 10)$.

The way I approached it was converting $X$ into a standard normal distribution so
$\frac{X-4}{3}$.

$P(1 \leq X < 10) = P(X < 10) - P(X \leq 1) = Z$ value for $\frac{10-4}{3} - Z$ value for $\frac{1-4}{3}$.

This does not give me the correct answer. Would really appreciate some help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have written so far is right. So you have $\Phi\left(\frac{6}{3}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{-3}{3}\right)=\Phi\left(2\right)-\Phi\left(-1\right)$. Some tables show values ​​for positive $z$ only. Due the symmetry around $0$ of the standardized normal distribution we have $\Phi\left(-x\right)=1-\Phi\left(x\right)$.  Then we get $\Phi\left(2\right)-\left(1-\Phi\left(1\right)\right)=\Phi\left(2\right)+\Phi\left(1\right)-1$. Now we take this [this table](https://www.soa.org/globalassets/assets/Files/Edu/2018/exam-srm-tables.pdf) and look up the corresponding values.

$P(1 \leq X < 10)=0.9772+0.8413-1=0.8185$